# Why are changes in VSCode all of a sudden not registering at localhost, only for one page?

Tags: google-chrome, go, visual-studio-code, caching, localhost

I have a pretty simple website using go templates. Everything was ok until today. I was playing around with bootstrap, and changes were showing up fine in the browser at localhost. I tried adding a conditional statement and noticed that suddenly no changes were showing up.

I removed the conditional statement to take things back to when everything was working but that didn't help. I can delete whole elements from my code now and they still show up in the browser and in dev tools. The only thing I can think of is that it's some sort of caching issue. I've disabled cache in dev tools, cleared cache from Chrome, tried it in an incognito window, and restarted my mac/browser with no change.

**The really weird thing is that other pages display changes fine**, it's only one page that isn't responding, so could it really be a caching issue?

Here is the code that was responding before I added the conditional statement(which is almost in the middle of the code):

```golang
{{template "base" .}}

{{ define "card" }}
    {{ $card := index .Cards 0 }}
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center">{{ $card.Name }}</h2><br>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <img src="../../static/img/cards/{{ $card.Img }}" alt="{{ $card.Img }}">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <p><strong>Arcana:</strong> {{ $card.Arcana }}</p>
                {{ if ne $card.Suit "Trump" }}
                    <p><strong>Suit:</strong> {{ $card.Suit }}</p>
                {{ end }}
                <p><strong>Element:</strong> {{ $card.Element }}</p>
                <p><strong>Upright Meanings:</strong>
                    <ul>
                    {{ range $card.Meanings.Upright }}
                        <li>{{ . }}</li>
                    {{ end }}
                    </ul>
                </p>
                <p><strong>Reversed Meanings:</strong>
                    <ul>
                    {{ range $card.Meanings.Reversed }}
                        <li>{{ . }}</li>
                    {{ end }}
                    </ul>    
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{{ end }}
```

And here is the same code at an earlier point when it was working for comparison:

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{ define "card" }}
    {{ $card := index .Cards 0 }}
    <h2>{{ $card.Name }}</h2><br>
    <img src="../../static/img/cards/{{ $card.Img }}" alt="{{ $card.Img }}">
    <p><strong>Arcana:</strong> {{ $card.Arcana }}</p>
    <p><strong>Suit:</strong> {{ $card.Suit }}</p>
    <p><strong>Element:</strong> {{ $card.Element }}</p>
    <p><strong>Upright Meanings:</strong>
        <ul>
        {{ range $card.Meanings.Upright }}
            <li>{{ . }}</li>
        {{ end }}
        </ul>
    </p>
    <p><strong>Reversed Meanings:</strong>
        <ul>
        {{ range $card.Meanings.Reversed }}
            <li>{{ . }}</li>
        {{ end }}
        </ul>    
    </p>
{{ end }}
```

I appreciate anyone's eyes on this, maybe I've missed something small, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to work on another page in the same project for awhile and suddenly the one page that wasn't rendering changes started responding. So, not sure what happened but maybe advice for anyone that runs into this, just leave it for awhile and work on something else haha! I'm sure there was a reason and would still like to know what it was if anyone comes across this.